# Bounded derivative implies uniform continuity on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f : (a,b) \to \mathbb{R}$  such that $f'$ exists and is bounded on $(a,b)$.

Then is $f$ uniformly continuous?

I have a hint to use the mean value theorem, but I'm not sure I can apply it to an open interval like this?  Does the bounded derivative imply that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ somehow?

Comment: Yes bounded derivatives necessarily do mean continuous on closed intervals

Comment: Like if $f(x)$ tends to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as x tends to the boundary values then $f'(x)$ wont have any bounds as slope would be $+\infty$ or $-\infty$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the MVT to check that $f$ is a Lipschitz function.

> Let $x,y \in (a,b)$. By the MVT, there is $z \in (a,b)$ between $x$ and $y$ with $f(x)-f(y) = f'(z)(x-y)$. Since $|f'| \leq M$ for some $M \geq 0$, we have: $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |f'(z)(x-y)| \leq M|x-y|.$$

Then check that every Lipschitz function is uniformly continuous.

> Let $\epsilon > 0$ and choose $\delta = \epsilon/M > 0$. So, if $|x-y| < \delta$, we get: $$|f(x)-f(y)| \leq M|x-y| < M \frac{\epsilon}{M} = \epsilon,$$and $\delta$ does not depend on the points $x$ and $y$.

Comment: This looks roughly like the proof I had written, but I discarded it after considering the requirements of the MVT.  Don't we require continuity on $[a,b]$ to apply it?

Comment: What are you trying to prove? That for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $x,y\in(a,b)$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$. For this you can just apply MVT on the interval $[x,y]$.

Comment: Take $x$ and $y$ in $(a,b)$, $x \leq y$. Then $a < x \leq y < b$, and you can apply the MVT in $\left[\frac{a+x}{2}, \frac{b+y}{2}\right]$.

Comment: David's suggestion is even better than mine. Good.

Comment: @IvoTerek How does this work? You are using the MVT but that requires $f(x)$ be continuous on $[a,b]$, which we do not have here. Your alteration of taking $a<x \leq y<b$ does solve the problem for sub-compact intervals but still hasn't shown $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,(a+x)/2) \cup ((b+y)/2,b)$. Have I missed something?

Comment: MVT requires continuity on $[a,b]$, true, but $x$ and $y$ were arbitrary and I ended with $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq M|x-y|$, and this $M$ is the same for every choice of $x$ and $y$. I don't think we have any problem here.

Comment: How can you claim this $f'(z)$ always works? And don't you need that $x > y$ for the MVT?