# Real Analysis | uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ be a function. Suppose $f'(x)$ exists for each $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is bounded at $\mathbb{R}$. Does it imply $f$ is uniformly continuous?

Comment: If you've already proved $\Leftarrow$, it would help avoid close-votes and down-votes if you give that proof.

Comment: I feel you being sarcasm, you could state that I was mistaken more directly or rather not help at all.

Comment: This question is similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473463/bounded-derivative-implies-uniform-continuity-on-an-open-interval. The basic idea is to use the MVT and the boundedness of $f'$

Comment: @X4J: I was not being sarcastic. Math.SE generally wants questions to have as much context as the asker can provide. It both helps other users tailor their answers as much to the asker's needs as possible, and establishes that the asker is not just looking for someone to do their work for them. (I don't necessarily think you were doing that, but it's not always easy to tell for sure.) ¶ Please don't accuse others of sarcasm unless you're actually sure, especially if English is not your first language.

Answer (score 2):

By Mean value theorem,
We know,
$|f(x)- f(y)|=|f'(c)(x-y)|$ for some $c$ in $(x,y)$ and for all $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Since, $f'$ is bounded ,$|f'|≤K$ for some $K$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
Then,
$|f(x)-f(y)|≤K|x-y|$ for any $x,y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Now, for any $\epsilon >0$ choose $\delta =\frac{\epsilon}{K}$
Then our job is done.

Comment: Thanks mate. What about the <= of the claim? I tried to think of a function which is defined all over R but failed